# Terraform Branches and circleci

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am working on a project creating different branches for the same terraform repository. Is there a way with Terraform and Circle CI to do this not using workspaces?

Comment: Ok, but what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have several branches on my repo in case we want to apply different changes to each branch for testing. So basically, to have isolated testing infrastructure services that will be released using a different branch. Is there a way to do it not with workspaces?

Comment: I mean, if you commit different things to different branches, you don't need workspaces. The thing I don't understand here is if one of the branches will transition into the main one or not. And AFAIK, you can checkout different branches with CircleCI. But still, I don't think you are going to get the answer you are looking for as the topic is way too broad.

Comment: Hi Marko, The idea would be to commit to a different branch a new feature of the release for example and to release it via Circle CI using that branch. I agree it is quite broad. But perhaps, about the topic of how we could do it with Circle CI and Terraform together?

Comment: The easiest way probably would be to use annotated tags and create different releases. That way you would be able to test the new version and the old one would still remain there as a fallback mechanism if the new version breaks something. But that's just from my experience. There are probably many more equally good or even better ways to achieve what you want. It does not matter if you scope the question to "Terraform and CircleCI" because you are asking for someone to give you a solution or a recommendation and that will not fly on SO.

Comment: Thank you Marko I will look into the annotated tag process. Possibly what I am looking for is to use "feature branches". Something like it shows in this post: https://hackernoon.com/from-feature-branches-to-feature-environments-with-terraform-10973ycb    but without having to use the workspaces as the structure of our repository wouldn't allow it straight away. Basically would be a module called feature-branch-x, feature-branch-y, feature-branch-z, etc... and circle ci would release the one we want to perhaps using conditionals. Is anything in this line you may have worked in the past?

Comment: Could be, I mean it's ok to start one way and later on to move to another one if it doesn't fit you. :)

Comment: Agree, It is an experimental process : ) Did you do an approach like this or do you have a possible idea about how to call the different modules in circle ci? I mean if we want to release feature-y using Terraform instead of x or z how we would do from circle ci?

Comment: Here's how would you call a different version of a module (and works even for different branches): https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/sources#selecting-a-revision

Comment: I think this is great Marko, it goes in the line I am looking for; I will test it.  Thank you :)

Comment: This is more now a CircleCI question: I was reviewing the previous link and in regards about how to select one module or another in the circle ci config, how would it be better if we just want to run one feature branch?

Comment: You could just use git tags (annotated, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_annotated_tags) and select the version you want, the same way you would select a branch. Then, if doesn't work as expected, you could just fall back to the previous version that was working until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Would the [Terraform Orb for CircleCI](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/terraform) be of any help to implement what you want?